# How to write one file from two files in groovy (Jenkins)?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have two *.hex files (can be handled like ASCII files) generated from a Jenkinsfile groovy pipeline build script.
After a successfull build there are the following files in the jobs workspace:

1. a.hex
2. b.hex

What i need is c.hex, which is just the two a.hex and b.hex glued together in one file.

In C it looks like this:

```
static void mergeIntelHexFiles(const char* aFile, const char* bFile, const char* mergedFile)
{
  FILE* readFileA  = fopen(aFile, "r");
  FILE* readFileB = fopen(bFile, "r");
  if (   (NULL != readFileA  )
      && (NULL != readFileB ))
  {
    FILE* writeFile = fopen(mergedFile, "w");
    if (NULL != writeFile)
    {
      char lineBuffer[MAX_PATH_LEN];

      while (NULL != fgets(lineBuffer, MAX_PATH_LEN, readFileA ))
      {
        if (NULL == strstr(lineBuffer, ":00000001FF"))
        { // it is not the last line of the file
          fputs(lineBuffer, writeFile); // copy the line without modification
        }
      }

      while (NULL != fgets(lineBuffer, MAX_PATH_LEN, readFileB ))
      {
        fputs(lineBuffer, writeFile); // copy the line without modification
      }

      fclose(writeFile);
    }
    fclose(readFileA);
    fclose(readFileB);
  }
}
```

This only copies every line of a.hex into c.hex and afterwards copies every line of b.hex into c.hex.

But in Jenkins Groovy I have no idea how to do this…

I could only find documentation for simple examples like [this](https://code-maven.com/jenkins-readfile-writefile)

So the question is how to combine two files into one in groovy?

Comment: `new File('c.hex').text = new File('a.hex').text + new File('b.hex').text` assuming they are just ASCII text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy has some nice overloaded methods on the File class as well as the overload '<<' operator that allows you to append content to a File. Your use case is easily solved with a single line of code:

```
new File("c.hex") <<  new File("a.hex").text <<  new File("b.hex").text
```

In your comment, you are asking how to merge the files and remove the last line of a.hex. It takes a little more code, but is still easy to accomplish:

```
def cHex = new File("c.hex")
def lines = new File("a.hex").readLines()
lines.eachWithIndex { String line, int idx -> if(idx < lines.size() - 1) cHex << line << '\n' }
cHex << new File("b.hex").text
```

Comment: Do you also know how to delete the last line of a.hex and than merge the files?